# Find the basis and its dimention of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given $S=\{x\in\Bbb R^4: x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=0, x_2+x_4=0\}$

So (...)

If $x_2+x_4=0 \implies x_2=-x_4$ then $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=0\implies x_1+x_2+x_3-x_2=0\implies x_1=-x_3\implies x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=0$

$X=(0,0,0,0)$ but $X$ is not linearly independent.

So $S$ is not a basis for $\Bbb R^4$

This sounds very strange. Someone can tell me if it is well done? and if not, can explain it a  bit?

Thanks!

***EDIT:***

I realized I made a mistake.
If $x_1=-x_3$ and $x_2=-x_4$ and let $X=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \in \Bbb R^4$ then
$X=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(x_1,x_2,-x_1,-x_2)\implies X= x_1(1,0,-1,0)+x_2(0,1,0,-1)$
Since $v_1$ and $v_2$

So, let $v_1=c_1(1,0,-1,0), v_2=c_2(0,1,0,-1)$both $\in \Bbb R^4$ with $c_1,c_2 \in \Bbb R$

$c_1=c_2=0$ then, $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent.

$S=gen[(1,0,-1,0);(0,1,0,-1)]$ is a basis for $\Bbb R^4$

Comment: Very loosely you have four degrees of freedom and two constraints, so you should have two degrees of freedom 'left over'.

Comment: Edited, please, look again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two vectors found are perfect and will span the whole S. so the dimension of S is 2 and please look at your last statement where it says its a basis of $ \mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: Is not a basis of $\Bbb R^4$?

Comment: The dimension of a subspace is the quantity of vectors of S?
if $S=gen[v_1,...,v_k]$ then the dimention is $k$ and it's a basis for $\Bbb R^k$?

Comment: @TomiSebastiánJuárez dimension doesn't mean the quantity of vectors in a subspace it does mean you could generate the whole set with two LI vectors of S.

Comment: how I can get the dimension?

Comment: dimension of a Vector space or subspace is nothing but the cardinality of the basis set.